# Fortify method authenticateUsing never being called

Tags: laravel, fortify

After calling the route `/login` with the `email` and `password` data, the method `authenticateUsing` is never being called, even though I've registered the `FortifyServiceProvider` on the `providers` array (app.php)

The boot method on the service provier:

```
public function boot(): void
{
    // dd('hit') --> Works...

    Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewUser::class);
    Fortify::updateUserProfileInformationUsing(UpdateUserProfileInformation::class);
    Fortify::updateUserPasswordsUsing(UpdateUserPassword::class);
    Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class);

    Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
        dd($request);

        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if ($user &&
            \Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            return $user;
        }

        return false;
    });

    RateLimiter::for('login', function (Request $request) {
        $throttleKey = Str::transliterate(Str::lower($request->input(Fortify::username())).'|'.$request->ip());

        return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($throttleKey);
    });

    RateLimiter::for('two-factor', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->session()->get('login.id'));
    });
}
```

The http call:

```
axios.post('/login', { email: email.value, password: password.value })
    .then(r => console.log(r))
```

Since I'm build an SPA, I've defined my routes as:

```
Route::get('{any?}', function() {
    return view('application');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

I've also tried to change the routes to use only `/signup`:

```
Route::get('signup', function() {
    return view('application');
});
```

But the result is the same, the method `authenticateUsing` is never called and the response are always a `302` followed by a `200`, no matter what input I use the response is always the same, is like fortify is not being used at all.

How can I call the `/login` route from fortify to use the authentication?

Comment: it might be a CSRF token isuue , except the login route from CSRF , VerifyCsrfToken.php add except , /login in array of this middleware

Comment: The `csrf` token is passed to the request (X-XCSRF-TOKEN), along with forfity I'm using sanctum.